# Ansible manage ssh users with templates

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I've got an ansible playbook  for adding over  50 ssh-users for a packer ami build.

Here is how my  /playbooks/roles/users/tasks/create_user.yml: looks like.

```
---
- name: "User {{ item.name }}"
  user:
    comment: "Add {{ item.name }} account"
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    home: "/data/companies/project/{{ item.name }}"
    state: present
    uid: "{{ item.uid }}"
    group: company
    groups: company
    shell: /sbin/nologin
    state: present
    generate_ssh_key: no
    password: "{{ item.password }}"

- name: "Create home directory for {{ item.name }}"
  file:
    path: "/data/companies/project/{{ item.name }}"
    state: directory
    owner: "{{ item.name }}"
    group: company
    mode: 0700
```

Here's how /playbooks/roles/users/vars/main.yml file looks like

```
---
location: UK
users:
  - name: user1
    password: $6$8T8lH2vS$JKIdqkQmHUHR/s75RYMguPyHTisnNrXIPOjJ9IWxMHB4LY9PJX.3rgkmfLCWAHDi5VYZno2ntlYm7Kkdy0iAZ.
    uid: 601
    location: UK
  - name: user2
    password: $6$8T8lH2vS$JKIdqkQmHUHR/s75RYMguPyHTisnNrXIPOjJ9IWxMHB4LY9PJX.3rgkmfLCWAHDi5VYZno2ntlYm7Kkdy0iAZ
    uid: 602
    location: USA
```

Here's how my "/playbooks/roles/users/tasks/main.yml" looks like

```
---
 - name: Create users based on location
   include: create_users.yml
   loop: "{{ users | selectattr('location', 'equalto', location) | list }}"
```

When the corresponding packer build has been run there are no errors but user1,user2 and their attributes are not getting created.

```
amazon-ebs: TASK [: Create users based on location] ***********************************
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
    amazon-ebs: default                    : ok=10   changed=7    unreachable=0    failed=0
    amazon-ebs:
```

Please can someone help me understand as to why users are not getting created? Thanks

Comment: You may want to read about [variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is commonly approached through the use of variables and loops. Extract all the variable stuff out into a list variable, containing dictionaries of params, then use a loop to read through and apply. So based on your role approach:

Create a task file containing the two tasks to run - /playbooks/roles/users/tasks/create_user.yml:

```
---

- name: User "{{ item.name }}"
  user:
    comment "{{ item.name }} company account"
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    home: "/data/company/{{ item.name }}"
    state: present
    uid: 666
    group: company
    groups: company
    shell: /bin/bash
    state: present
    generate_ssh_key: no
    password: "{{ item.password }}"

- name: "Create home directory for {{ item.name }}"
  file:
    path: "/data/company/{{ item.name }}"
    state: directory
    owner: "{{ item.name }}"
    group: company
    mode: 0700
```

Create a vars file containing your users - /playbooks/roles/users/vars/main.yml:

```
---

location: UK   # This will be your default. It can be overridden in a variety of places
users:
  - name: user1
    password: <some password>
    location: US
  - name: user2
    password: <some password>
    location: UK
  - name: user3
    password: <some password>
    location: UK
```

then in /playbooks/roles/users/tasks/main.yml:

```
---

- name: Create users based on location
  include: create_user.yml
  loop: "{{ users | selectattr('location', 'equalto', location) | list }}"
```

Hopefully most of it is self explanatory. Because you are using a role, by placing the users variable in `/playbooks/roles/users/vars/main.yml`, the variable is automatically made available. The `users | selectattr('location', 'equalto', location)` expression, takes the `user` variable and filters the list to only include objects where the 'location' element is equal to the value specified in the 'location' variable.

[Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#)

[Loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html)

[Roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html)

Comment: Thanks so much. I will try this out and get back to you if I have any queries

Comment: I just tested the code thanks once again for your help. However It complains about the variable

Comment: You will have to give me more than 'However It complains about the variable' - I have no way of knowing what is going on.  Update your question with the actual code you have tried and the exact error.

Comment: :) Actually I hit alt+enter for a newline  to paste the error and some info but it got posted instead. Its is extremely hard to make use of the comment option. I will update question with what I've tried instead. Thanks. Apologies I meant no disrespect.

Comment: Took a guess at the problem, and noticed problems in `create_user.yml`. Have edited my answer. Note the changes from '=' to ':' and quotes around `{{ item.name }}` which I should not have missed off.

Comment: oh yes trying again.

Comment: I've updated the code sir. Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: The code example was based on a general playbook approach. I had missed that you were already using roles and things have become confused as a result. I have updated my code to work within a role.

Comment: Thanks so much. Tried the latest update, There are no errors this time but users are not getting created. I updated my question with the latest situation. Really appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Your question says you have called the file 'create_users.yml' but your code is calling 'create_user.yml'. Other than that, the code works for me.

Comment: Thanks clock. Please ignore The create _user(S) discrepancy you’ve spotted it was just a typo I’ve made when typing the question. I confirm Everything was written and run the way it was supposed to. Still can’t figure out why it doesn’t do anything, checked the code like a 100 times but to no avail. I’m sure this something really minor. I will try to figure out somehow. If you find anything interesting though please let me know. Thanks. :)

Comment: I would suggest on working on building up your debug skills. Basically, you can add the `debug` module in strategic places, to help troubleshoot. E.g. What do the `users` and `location` variables actually contain before you pass them to the looped include task. What does the `item` variable contain inside the looped task, etc. If your code is doing nothing, that is likely either because there is nothing to loop, or the users & dir's already exist on the system.

Answer (score 0):

Some additional hints, you can use defaults too.
Also, in case you want to protect the encrypted passwords, you can store them in Ansible Vault:

users.yml example:

```
users:
- name: user1
  uid: 666
  group: group1
  groups: [allusers]
  comment: User One
  home: /home/user1
  shell: /bin/bash

passwords: "{{ vault_passwords }}"
```

The vault file you crypt with 'ansible-vault' command looks like (decrypted):

```
passwords:
- name: user1
  password: $6$509875346RH.RAaVNW2iWtf/QJ4zUGaJiEyh.
```

playbook included tasks file example:

```
  - name: Set up user accounts
    user:
      name: "{{ item.name }}"
      create_home: '{{ item.createhome | default("no") }}'
      uid: "{{ item.uid }}"
      group: "{{ item.group }}"
      state: '{{ item.state | default("present") }}'
      comment: '{{ item.comment | default("Ansible created comment") }}'
      home: "{{ item.home }}"
      shell: '{{ item.shell | default("/bin/bash") }}'
    with_items: "{{ users }}"

  - name: Set up user account passwords
    user:
      name: "{{ item.name }}"
      password: '{{ item.password | default("*") }}'
    with_items: "{{ passwords }}"
```

Comment: Thanks Nemo. I’ve updated my question with more context and a better piece of code.